# Set property name based off value of another property in an interface

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to specify a list of allowed values for an interface property name?

For example, say I have an interface like so:

```
export interface DashboardRequest {
  name?: string;
  description?: string;
  type: 'foo'|'bar';
  ['foo' |'bar']: any;
}
```

I'd like a property name to be restricted to possible values of another property in my interface.

I know the above is incorrect, but hopefully illustrates what I want to achieve.

Whats the correct approach here?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a discriminated union (and an intersection to avoid duplicating common fields)

```
export type DashboardRequest = {
  name?: string;
  description?: string;
} & (
    { type: 'foo'; 'foo': any } |
    { type: 'bar'; 'bar': any }
  )

let foo: DashboardRequest = {
  type: "foo",
  foo : ""
}

let bar: DashboardRequest = {
  type: "bar",
  bar : ""
}

let err: DashboardRequest = {
  type: "bar",
  foo : "" // err
}
```

Comment: This is very clever. I like this a lot.